# How to align picture with list of html?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am new to html coding and I could not find exact and clear solution for my problem.

I want to create a page with this format: I want to do the page with list of html.

[image]

Here is my html code:

[image]

Although I made alignment center my picture is on the left side of the page. What is wrong or missing with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no** `float: center`. Only `float: left` and `float: right`. You can *left-float* all of `<p>` inside the `<li>` and set the width of them to `33.33%`.

In this case the image has to be responsive:

```
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Every `<li>` represent a row

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>text</p>
    <p><img src=""></p>
    <p>text</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**In total**

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul>li>* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 33.333%;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </p>
    <p class="text-center">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </p>
    <p>
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>

  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="full-width">
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="full-width">
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <li>
      <p>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      </p>
      <p class="text-center">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
      </p>
      <p>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is what I want to do but I could not run from my notepad.html. Do I place ul>li part at the head part of html?

Comment: Thats ok now @Peter Leger. I am able to run it thanks. But I did not understand the ul>li part. If I want to add last paragraph with a picture but this time picture is left with alignment. How can I manage?

Comment: Thanx but I want to do last paragraph with picture to left alignment. Text to wrap around this left aligned picture. When I tried it always makes as if there are 3 columns for the last paragraph.

Comment: Thats ok now. It worked. Thank you very much, I added a few new style and I got what I wanted to do.

Answer (score -1):

You would probably be best looking into using a grid system. I would recommend using Twitter's Bootstrap - definitely the best as easiest to start using

http://getbootstrap.com/